# how to read a file from a local directory from python code in a docker container?

Tags: python, pandas, docker

I have tried to containerize my python code , this is working, building the docker image, running the container and invoking the python code in my app.py file. next, i want to be able to upload the sample.txt file that my python code reads from the root of the application to process some data, sample.txt in the example below. but this file needs to be updated and i want to be able to update this file and run the container, without building the image. how can i create/mount a directory and put the csv file there and give the path to my python code?

app.py

```
import pandas as pd
print pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
...
```

docker file

```
# Dockerfile
FROM debian:10.3-slim

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y dist-upgrade

RUN apt-get -y install apt-utils \
    build-essential \
    python3 \
    gcc \
    python3-dev \
    python3-pip \
    python3-numpy \
    python3-pandas

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the python script
COPY modbus_to_influx.py /app/modbus_to_influx.py

CMD ["python3", "app.py"]
```

requirements.txt

```
numpy 
pandas
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `docker run`, you can [(bind) mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) folders/files on the host as folders/files on the container:

```bash
docker run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
--volume=/path/to/host/file:/path/to/container/file \
your-container
```

For example if you had `example.csv` on the host's root directory and you want it to be accessible to your Python app in the container in `/data`, you would:

```bash
docker run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
--volume=/example.csv:/data/example.csv \
your-container
```

> **NOTE** That the file name must be included in the `host-path` and `container-path` elements of `--volume=host-path:container-path` permitting you to rename the host's file (`example.csv`) to something else on the container too.

Comment: @DanWilkin - one follow up question, thought this would be obvious , but when i tested it didn't work. if I am writing a file from my pthon code , instead of reading , how would it work. can i mount/map a directory such that the file will be saved to a directory on my local machine.

Comment: Yes, you must mount a folder in that case because a non-existent file can't be mounted. Docker will create a folder on the host for a non-existent path (either file or folder)

Comment: thanks again. i'm running the container as such ->  docker run -it  --rm --volume=/home/somefile.csv:/targetFolder/somefile.csv. it creates the folder by the name in my local machine, but i'm looking to create a file. in my python code, im creating the file programatically as dataframe.to_csv(f"targetFolder/somefile.csv"). not sure what i'm doing wrong here

Comment: Yes, that's the expected behavior. Please see my previous comment. If `/home/somefile.csv` doesn't exist on the host when it is mounted into a container (possibly because your container|Python) will create it, Docker will create a folder (!) called `/home/somefile.csv`. What you should do instead is `--volume=/home/someFolder:/targetFolder`. When your code writes `/targetFolder/somefile.csv` in the container, the file `/home/someFolder/somefile.csv` will be written to the host.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH|-`
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/